# Check file exist with condition such as *visio*.exe

Tags: batch-file

I want to know how to check file exist as this post topic for my login script on server.

My idea is check visio that installed on user laptop but there are many version of visio.

We have 2007, 2010 and 2013 of visio with x86 or x64 version.

How can I check it ?. This is my script.

```
*if exist "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office\Office13\VISIO.EXE" Action
if exist "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Office\Office13\VISIO.EXE" Action

if exist "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\VISIO.EXE" Action
if exist "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Office\Office14\VISIO.EXE Action

if exist "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office\Office15\VISIO.EXE" Action
if exist "%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Office\Office15\VISIO.EXE" Action*
```

I think that is ugly coding. How can I shorter it like this:

```
if exist %systemdrive%\*\VISIO.EXE Action
```

Comment: I got the solution by Burhan Khalid and adapt to my knowledge as below code

Comment: reg query HKCR\Applications\visio.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 md \\Bkfilesvr\it\SoftwareCheck\VISIO\%computername%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`reg query`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742028.aspx) command and query for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Visio.Application`, if it exists, visio is installed.

I don't have visio installed so for me it gives:

```
C:\>reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Visio.Application
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

However, I do have Word installed, and so I get:

```
C:\>reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Microsoft Word Application

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CLSID
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application\CurVer
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I using your it as my script now.

Comment: reg query HKCR\Applications\visio.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 md \\svr\it\SoftwareCheck\VISIO\%computername%

Answer (score 0):

The command to search a file (by pattern) in a directory or path under windows is called `where`.

This (all on a single line) will return the path found and set errorlevel 0/1:

```
where "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office\Office13;
      %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14;
      %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft Office\Office15:VISIO.EXE"
```

You can use the "for" trick to actually work on the results (but it is easier to specify the directories in PATH and just use "visio.exe")

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ^
    ('where "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin:java.exe"')^
    do @set JAVA=%a
```

This example will pick the last java found.